# how to run 10000 goroutines in parallel where each routine calls an api?

Tags: api, go, concurrency, goroutine

I have the following code, where I am trying to call an api 10000 times but i am getting errors:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    nCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(nCPU)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    totalRequests := 100000
    wg.Add(totalRequests)

    fmt.Println("Starting Go Routines")

    start := time.Now()
    total := 0

    for i := 0; i < totalRequests; i++ {

        go func(current int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            startFunc := time.Now()
            _, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/event/list")
            // resp, err := http.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me" + "?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=" + "CAACEdEose0cBAEpQvcsvVMQu5oZCyyDjcEPQi9yCdiXimm4F0AYexGHPZAJHgpyrFOJN5X1VMcicNJjlkaCquUqHMZAfRrtxx6K9cRIROrA0OmbqAqCcg8ZA3qJZCHCl68I1n4LtFb5qxPcotlP5ne5PBakK0OUa7sc6FAOWwByOnFtNZBpIe8XDeM4YFa33sDfftVUpZCoBgZDZD")

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            // defer resp.Body.Close()
            elapsedFunc := time.Since(startFunc)
            fmt.Println("The request (", current, ") took", elapsedFunc, "No of requests completed", total)
            total++

        }(i)

    }

    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("\nThe total time with cores", elapsed)
    fmt.Println("\nTerminating Program")
}
```

The errors I am getting:

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/event/list: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: socket: too many open files
The request ( 5390 ) took 1.619876633s No of requests completed 2781
Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/event/list: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: socket: too many open files
The request ( 7348 ) took 650.609825ms No of requests completed 1445
```

Comment: you're trying to open too many sockets. Either limit the concurrent requests, or increase the process limits.

Comment: you are also incrementing total in an unsafe way, it easily won't add up to the number of runs.  Use atomic.AddInt64(&total) (and change to total := int64(0))

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: that error is caused by running out of file descriptors. Has nothing to do with the remote host.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. My mistake.

Comment: can i restrict like only 1024 requests at a time (ie go routines) amd rest have to wait ??

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned in the comments, your main issue is that you are exceeding the open file limit of the process.

You can easily implement a semaphore using channels to limit concurrency:

```
totalRequests := 100000
concurrency := 1024
sem := make(chan bool, concurrency)

start := time.Now()
total := int32(0)

for i := 0; i < totalRequests; i++ {
    sem <- true

    go func(current int) {
        startTime := time.Now()

        // Make request here

        elapsedTime := time.Since(startTime)
        atomic.AddInt32(&total, 1)
        fmt.Printf("Request %d took %s. Requests completed: %d\n", current, elapsedTime, atomic.LoadInt32(&total))

        <-sem
    }(i)
}

for i := 0; i < cap(sem); i++ {
    sem <- true
}
elapsedTotal := time.Since(start)
fmt.Printf("\nTotal time elapsed: %s\n", elapsedTotal)
```

This will limit the number of parallel requests to whatever is specified in `concurrency`.

As you can see, the `total` variable is incremented using the `atomic` package since we are modifying that variable from potentially parallel goroutines, which could have produced an incorrect total when modified unsafely, as you did.

See this blog post for the original example & explanation of limiting concurrency in Go: http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by JimB below, another common approach is to have `concurrency` number of goroutines doing the work while we feed it to them. Here's a generic `do` function that one might use for this:

```
func do(total, concurrency int, fn func(int)) {
    workQueue := make(chan int, concurrency)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(concurrency)

    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
        go func() {
            for i := range workQueue {
                fn(i)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < total; i++ {
        workQueue <- i
    }
    close(workQueue)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

We spawn `concurrency` goroutines and then start sending values to the `workQueue` channel until `total` is sent. By closing the `workQueue` channel we effectively terminate the range loops in our goroutines. After that we just wait until all the remaining goroutines finish running.

For the use case in question, it could be used like this:

```
totalRequests := 1000000
concurrency := 1024

do(totalRequests, concurrency, func(i int) {
    // Make request here

    fmt.Printf("Request %d done.\n", i)
})
```

Comment: Another more common pattern is to have "concurrency" number of worker goroutines ranging over a channel, instead of spawning a new goroutine each time.

Comment: @JimB Right, will add an additional example.